# c# Fill textbox while listbox is being filled

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code:

```
private void _1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillA();
    FillB();
    // Tried these lines too but they show listbox values but not textbox value
    //    var t2 = Task.Run(() => FillA());
    //    FillB();    
}

private void FillA()
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            listBox1.Update();
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    }));
}

private void FillB()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000); //1 seconds delay
    textBox1.Text = "Hello World!";
}
```

When the page loads the `listbox` should starts showing the number 1, 2, 3... and then after few seconds of delay the textbox should show the `Hello World!` value but the listbox should keep growing. How do I ensure that first the listbox should start filling and then the textbox should fill. I don't want to wait for the filling of the listbox and then textbox to be filled.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Edit:** 
This is just a sample code. In actual production there would be two processes and the second process will start once the first process is started fetching data and storing in listbox.

The first process should keep on going. I can't stop it in middle as it would create inconsistency in the data.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(3000) will stop your UI Thread and nothing will be grown or shown for that period. Read about Multithreading UI in win forms here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

Comment: Also your `for` loop seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes the listbox shows values but textbox is not filled.

Comment: @ S.Akbar - its a sample one but the idea is the listbox will keep receiving the values and it will only stop when the form is closed.

Comment: well your for loop `for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)` will go forever, and since it is not created as async, the method `FillB` will never be executed since `FillA` is never completed. if i were you i would go with `Task.Run`

Comment: I tried this  var t2 = Task.Run(() => FillA());
            FillB(); But it too does not show the value in textbox though the listbox is growing

Comment: Moreover, if you are going to go with regular updates, instead of firing up an infinite loop and sleeping threads, you can go with `Timer`s, especially if your refreshing intervals are less than 60Hz or so.

Comment: maybe you can try `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>FillA())` By the way when using Task for `FillA`, *do not call the method by `this.Invoke`*, just use your `for` loop.

Comment: @mcy - thank you for your suggestion, tried but still the textbox does not show the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146729/discussion-between-mcy-and-user1254053).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Sleep. Instead use Timer-class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

- Configure a timeout of 1s.
- Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer:

  ```
  aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
  ```
- In method OnTimedEvent you can increment a integer-variable **i**.
- Depending on value of **i** you fill first listbox and if value is higher fill the other Listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add all items at once to the listbox and update the textbox in between as these operations are done synchronously in WindowsForms.

Instead you should add only a subset of items to the listbox, update the textbox and then continue adding items to the listbox.

To not freeze the GUI in between waiting for operations, you can use `async\await` combination instead of `Thread.Sleep()`.

```
private async void _1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await AddInitialListBoxItems();
    await FillTextBox();
    await AddRemainingListBoxItems();
}

private async Task AddInitialListBoxItems()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        listBox1.Update();
        await Task.Delay(25);
    }
}

private async Task FillTextBox()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000); //1 seconds delay
    textBox1.Text = "Hello World!";
}

private async Task AddRemainingListBoxItems()
{
    for (int i = 11; i < 100; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        listBox1.Update();
        await Task.Delay(25);
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives error- Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: There was the `async` keyword missing in `_1_Load` function earlier on but now the excerpt should work fine. Could share your code and indicate which line throws an error?

Comment: thanks Krzysztof Bracha . This does not throw any error now but my purpose is not solved. I cannot stop the process and restart it again as stopping will make inconsistency in the values

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `Timer`s instead of direct threading, this might help you. It worked on my pc:

**Edit** since you need the textbox to get written after some delay, you need to use a timer for it as well. I have edited the code below. Textbox is written after 1 seconds of listbox population starting.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int counter = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 25;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timerTextbox = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timerTextbox.Interval = 1000;
        timerTextbox.Tick += TimerTextbox_Tick; ;
        timerTextbox.Start();


    }

    private void TimerTextbox_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillB();
        (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Timer).Stop();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(counter.ToString());
        counter++;
        listBox1.Update();
    }

    private void FillB()
    {
      textBox1.Text = "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Of course when you call `Thread.Sleep(3000); //1 seconds delay` on `Load` event (3000 ms is 3 seconds btw), your form will be shown 3 seconds late.

Comment: Both textbox and listbox shows the value at same time.. It should first start showing values in listbox and then in textbox

Comment: @user1254053 I have updated so that textbox is edited 1 second after listbox starts populating.